# Joins on multiple condition with each condition result

Tags: join, conditional-statements

I want to get the details of each condition result as true or false used in a join. For example below is the case

```
select emp.emp_id,emp.emp_name,hr.department,hr.salary 
from employee emp left outer join HR
on emp.empId=HR.emp_id 
and emp.emp_name=HR.emp_name
and emp.department=hr.department
and emp.salary=hr.salary;
```

now lets say first join condition emp_id is true and remaining are false. I want to get an output as

```
emp.emp_id,emp.emp_name,hr.department,hr.salary

true,false,false,false
```

and if first two conditions are true the output should be

```
true,true,false,false
```

and so on. Please ignore the database design here as it is taken just as an example. Thanks

Jafery

Answer (score 0):

This might be along the lines of what you want to do here:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM HR WHERE emp.empId = HR.empID)
         THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS emp_id,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM HR WHERE emp.emp_name = HR.emp_name)
         THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS emp_name,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM HR WHERE emp.department = HR.department)
         THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS department,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM HR WHERE emp.salary = HR.salary)
         THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS salary
FROM employee emp;
```

Each of the `CASE` with `EXISTS` statements probes, for record in the `employee` table, the `HR` table to see if it can find at least one matching record, for that particular column.

Note that this answer might not reflect an actual join, where a record in `employee` could potentially match *multiple* records in `HR`.  But, in this case, it is not well defined what it would mean for a single column alone to match or not match.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN emp.emp_id = HR.emp_id THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' as [emp_id],
CASE WHEN emp.emp_name = HR.emp_name THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' as [emp_name],
CASE WHEN emp.department = HR.department THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' as [department],
CASE WHEN emp.salary = HR.salary THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' as [salary],
from employee emp left outer join HR
on emp.empId=HR.emp_id 
and emp.emp_name=HR.emp_name
and emp.department=hr.department
and emp.salary=hr.salary
```

Comment: IMHO this statement will not give any result from HR table if any one of the join condition is false. So we can not compare columns of employee with HR as all HR fields will be null if all conditions are not true